# GCC Undefined Reference to xxx

Tags: objective-c, gcc

I'm making a simple test to see if I can run Objective-C on Linux without GNUStep, so I followed an example here on SO to get it running, here's my code:

```
//WSObject.h
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
@interface WSObject
+ (id) alloc;
- (void) dealloc;
- (void) hello;
@end


//WSObject.m
#include "WSObject.h"
@implementation WSObject
+ (id) alloc {
    return class_createInstance(self, 0);
}

+ (void) dealloc {
    object_dispose(self);
}

+ (void) hello {
    puts("Hello, world");
}
@end


//test.m
#include "WSObject.h"
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    WSObject *obj = [WSObject alloc];
    [obj hello];
    [obj dealloc];
    return 0;
}
```

When I then try to compile it with `gcc test.m -o test -lobjc`
I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccDzvsol.o:(.data+0x80): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_WSObject'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help?

Comment: Compile and link WSObject.m as well?

Comment: right, derp of course.. it's been ages since I last used gcc